# Unknown column 'product_code' in 'field list on my prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Sir when i go to save any product then i see this error. so can any help how can i fix it

**Unknown column 'product_code' in 'field list**

UPDATE `ps_product` SET `id_product` = '430',`id_shop_default` = '1',`id_manufacturer` = '0',`id_supplier` = '0',`reference` = '',`supplier_reference` = '',`location` = '',`width` = '0',`height` = '0',`depth` = '0',`weight` = '0',`quantity_discount` = '0',`ean13` = '',`upc` = '',`cache_is_pack` = '0',`cache_has_attachments` = '0',`is_virtual` = '0',`id_category_default` = '12',`id_tax_rules_group` = '0',`on_sale` = '0',`online_only` = '0',`ecotax` = '0',`minimal_quantity` = '1',`price` = '49.99',`wholesale_price` = '29.99',`unity` = '',`unit_price_ratio` = '0',`additional_shipping_cost` = '0',`customizable` = '0',`text_fields` = '0',`uploadable_files` = '0',`active` = '1',`redirect_type` = '404',`id_product_redirected` = '0',`available_for_order` = '1',`available_date` = '0000-00-00',`condition` = 'new',`show_price` = '1',`indexed` = '0',`visibility` = 'both',`cache_default_attribute` = '0',`advanced_stock_management` = '0',`date_add` = '2017-06-29 23:34:25',`date_upd` = '2017-07-04 00:41:34',`pack_stock_type` = '3',`product_code` = '' WHERE `id_product` = 430

Comment: The error stating that there is no column with such name in your table. Try checking your database for that & also  check this code product_code = '' WHERE id_product = 430 . It seems error prone to me

Comment: thanks sir for your help but can you please tell me details ?

Comment: instead of this `product_code = '' WHERE id_product = 430` try running query after removing `product_code` like pack_stock_type = '3' WHERE id_product = 430 and run your query again see if it works